# Javascript most efficient way to filter array with multiple conditional arguments

Tags: javascript, filter

I have two arguments that are optional that I want to use to filter the array.

As they are optional i am using two if statements, but I am curious if there is a more efficient/shorthand way.

```
// initializing list of users
var users = [{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'johnson@mail.com',
    age: 25,
    address: 'USA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    email: 'tom@mail.com',
    age: 35,
    address: 'England'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    email: 'mark@mail.com',
    age: 28,
    address: 'England'
  }
];


if (args.name){
    users = users.filter(x => x.name == args.name);
}

if (args.address){
    users = users.filter(x => x.address == args.address);
}

return users;
```

Comment: *"shorthand"*: isn't this short already? *"efficient"*: do you have a problem with timings? I mean, old-fashioned `for` loops are the fastest, but why would you? Moreover, questions about performance and style are more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can create a method and pass the parameter on what property you want to filter the data .

Answer (score 0):

You could use the entries of `args`.

```
const entries = Object.entries(args);

return users.filter(user => entries.every(([k, v]) => user[k] === v));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way?

```js
if (args.name || args.address){
    users = users.filter(x => x.name == args.name || x.address == args.address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the conditionals into one filter statement to only walk through the array once:

```js
function filter(args) {
// initializing list of users
var users = [{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'johnson@mail.com',
    age: 25,
    address: 'USA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    email: 'tom@mail.com',
    age: 35,
    address: 'England'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    email: 'mark@mail.com',
    age: 28,
    address: 'England'
  }
];


let conditionals = [];

if (args.name){
    conditionals.push(x => x.name == args.name);
}

if (args.address){
    conditionals.push(x => x.address == args.address);    
}


return users.filter(x => conditionals.every(c => c(x));

}
```

Please bear in mind that the real-world impact of this optimisation is really low if you are not dealing with enormous amounts of data

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper function for your needs and then use it in your code

```js
const users = [{
    name: 'John',
    email: 'johnson@mail.com',
    age: 25,
    address: 'USA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom',
    email: 'tom@mail.com',
    age: 35,
    address: 'England'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    email: 'mark@mail.com',
    age: 28,
    address: 'England'
  }
];

// Filter function
const fltr = (obj, search) => {
  const res = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    for(let key in search) {
      let add = true;
      for(let key in search) {
        if(obj[i][key] && obj[i][key] === search[key]) add = true;
        if(!obj[i][key] || obj[i][key] !== search[key]) {
          add = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(add) res.push(obj[i]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

//
// Args
const args = {
  address: "England"
};

// Use your function in your code, fast and easy
const res = fltr(users, args);

// Log
console.log(res);
```